# How do shift registers work on the gate level?

Tags: flipflop, shift-register

I am trying to understand how a serial to parallel shift register works on the gate level. Where I want to shift/load a bit each clock cycle.
I  found this schematic for a positive edge triggered D flip flop which works great. Trying to hook them up in series though, they all load the value on the data D line as they share the same clock. How then do these work such that they can load/shift a bit on the data input for each clock cycle?
Thanks
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick with flip-flops is that they have a non-zero clock to output delay. This means that when you cascade them, the next flop down the line can grab the current flop’s state *before* it changes. So the 'next' flop is one cycle behind its upstream neighbor.

This clock-to-output delay amounts to a ‘grace period’ for that next flop to grab that state and clock it out. As long as there is enough clock-to-output delay, this works fine: the shift register you show is a series of 1-cycle delays (I added a sim below.)

If however there is some extra inserted clock delay on the next flop relative to the current flop (that is, there is *clock skew*), the next flop could catch the state while the current flop is still in the middle of changing its state, and thus have an unpredictable post-clock value. This situation is called a *hold time violation*, and is one key design parameter for clocked systems.

The other key clocked-system parameter is *setup time*, that is, how long does the data need to be stable ('set up') before the rising edge of the clock. If the next flop input data changes before it has settled on it, its output state after clock rise can again be unpredictable. This becomes more of an issue as the cycle time gets smaller.

In the bigger picture, every flip flop has a sampling window relative to the clock where the input data must be stable. This is the time interval between minimum input setup and minimum input hold. I call this the *validity window*, and it must be met for the system to be reliable.

To ensure your system will work sometimes you need to understand your flip flop output delay and setup / hold characteristics, taking into account your system clock skews and your desired clock rate.

In other words:

- hold time requirement: (output delay min - clock skew) > input hold min
- setup time requirement: (cycle time - output delay max - clock skew) > input setup min

Most of the time this isn't so hard. Flip-flops in small-scale logic like TTL or CMOS are generally designed to require zero hold time (internally, they insert delay on the input relative to the clock.) This makes system design somewhat simpler.

---

BONUS: A Falstad Sim ([simulate it here](https://falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcZYA4BsB2ATNzZsEBOVA9EBSCkAFgGYKBTAWjDACgAZEZuu8hJnLMacCkKjgQAMwCGAGwDOjapHYAlHn3I10NHqKq79EbODHZoSS0iowE7MAgisiZ7KJ6oqHuyDNIDk4uYG4g2l5UET6SDgDuPKHuCMJJ-jhQ7Amu7hnM3uGQ%20mrZBXRFkeH8mdlpdNhUOYXFWYlh5fr5PhkllXhmXf6evYM0RMIFxjVtAdiolWPkI2kINJ0rc9ODCJvb6HatTYuVO-PLYTQFR%20OZwTMU%20yePMVRBzvdTo3qSDIGtbGY6KgTARwjtpkYwOQAeFgRDaPVJDQodMYcjoaC1mdWlE4WiUb0ougzrCWncjJdkGYsZIzK9HO8ouCYXRwTE-rULpSjojztTEYMgS1SrjOmVqoSqhMohKcbRvl9hR8Fb55UrmKrPqrWXTDtrwU0dVsIlrPFM%20eJhBFBEtDmlcJ0Hf4PFsnU6NS79tjsk6vZU-SMCn69gcEuiQH7wylQ%20kzJGUQHWv1nfpk4mEh0U7Gs71MzbwI9871CORifMS2rphWjZmjcWUpXq2zWpmphXza1jlNwx2wzcTSjop3B3Dw0OMxV6NSR0rW5TW7yGRBjka-XX-NQ3subjTI5SXhRO-3ibR%203Deiu4fHbQlrxHIPMaRed4iuwSjzoEw-SdM11fv3WS7NJWPbfFEm5AXmjxRs8G70hO%20iXFEk43LmKGfgImwXiipy0DhzwthUqz6HmWGEfouE9qhw46DuKK9nh5DJuGqpoSRk4osmbHhA0wGZth5CtoOsoIdmY4VNx1YVFxkEVAOgkSnBh53JmmqccMG4clSYJmFCTK6gkek6QWrwSCMmoqp4ZaulZqDlg21lqAAHjwcyvOgwjYOgvzoEQtBDCAAAi7AuQQmDhGs4A0EgdA0OFqb6AAiiF96AnQ4XoLxsVGAFyUuU6gg%20Mi4gMAlQUpTgplUJg6Ulf5LrBaFkAkFU4VsIOZq5UB3hFVQRCgqxmnKe8PVSiA-VpUsSnxCAo0VnNPStAtZgTcBvSrZmG0ibNYj1FQo38Utu0VKtMkJKdGSncMrSrcct1gUdrybLd1EJKNxE7U93rjaCuGrdG0yjXdv1kW9YhIZ9p62nc72PP9sF0sNEBA9893FOEEGGWAcl4tjJHNudFwomwONKkQFyIuT043sgHEYpO%2043e0uN09MVPhCe7NCrc7zszSJOIfu01AVzzJ48Z7KHmDFLzEDi7SwiK2gtz63K3CW001z1Qa2zFyo5iD0K1MmDggxJvUt85sS60VtGgdBMgFb1lWwx70SOgDZFo9WZCOWLq9L7PsnumjvB9%20q0hxH4e-QRhmiPMfpgPHDwxmQ%20iJ8nIdp1m2dZ9gNxOtnTq9AQNz5mw4Je4ZHgJ3Z4A15WJcN0apeCQ7BCUlMHfzIB1c7t83eN-8lyPgPycMUndcREnAHbTPPd4sn471y%20ulL%20e-z5zolKt4rPMQJPPfMvs%20m0hBdyH7QO8n1fJKIzNl-8PMj8b3HU94jf4Yl5-xOf4zb%20PkRJfL%20w867hj0qKVEN9uYQOthfLelZ56Nwxn8eBZdHhIIBgeB%20CCIa72OE3HcNxMGgyit%20XCmDY4rwEJFXeuFCGYWfuPV6ZDHzEPHobVh2YkGsU3v2CoPDFp90ErxXeh044AQEUvOeCDkxIPEdQ-wDZd4yTQQpaE0ipr3yAiozwPCNIBEPKFYgDA%20AmHQGwVq9UkopQIDhTAVACB8DqmVYKCQKzO3BI5G2Xi66D28beBsq5PZmVaGuLxQT25OEBGLSuoSsZyViTEgyJlT5QkRIBAA9lIMCtBmp%20VsLAeARAhApEIJIDg2TWQRnRqIcmqgilwBKR7TKthwDsGyZgPyuS6kFKgI05qpTWkVI6QWBOtT8kNPgIMlp5THGjLAA4mpSJJmFOmc0spbTKngAyD01Z-T1lDLme0oAA)):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The first FF latches the value on the data in line. The second FF simulatiously sees the last bit (the output from FF1) on the input and latches that. And so one. So with each clock the bits are shifted one step further to the right.

Comment: So I am feeding in Q to the D line of the next FF etc.. The problem is that when the first D is high an the clock goes high, that value feeds through all the FFs. How can I prevent it from feeding through them all, as with 1 clock cycle I also want it to feed through 1. Thanks!

Comment: @Barlo67: Since the clock is edge triggered, not level sensitive (which would be a "latch" not a "flip-flop") that won't happen.

Comment: Ah ok, but still with a common clock all of these latches are edge triggered together and the initial value on D goes through all of them, when it should only go through 1? Is there something wrong with the above circuit?

Comment: @Barlo67 Have you built this circuit or just simulated it?

Comment: @Barlo67: The above circuit is fine, it's your assumption that data takes negative time to pass through a flip-flop (so that an output triggered by a clock edge can arrive to the next flop-flop before the clock edge) that is incorrect.  Synchronous (edge-triggered) logic neither looks into the future (to see what the upstream flip-flop is going to produce as a result of the clock edge) or make changes in the past (to have a result caused by a clock edge ready at the clock edge)

Answer (score 0):

To build reliable shift registers you need master-slave flipflops.
If you don't use master-slave flipflops, it is possible that a data bit is shifted 2 places instead of 1 or no place at all.

Each flipflop may have a small difference in clock delay and clock level voltage and the clock signal may have slow rise and fall times. Therefore it is not guaranteed that all flipflops of the shift register react at exactly the same time.

Master-slave flipflops are a chain of two flipflops, the first one, the master stores the input at the rising edge of clock. the second one, the slave takes the data from the master at the falling edge of the clock.

Using master-slave flipflops prevents shifting by several steps instead of one.

See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)#Master%E2%80%93slave_edge-triggered_D_flip-flop)

Comment: Classical edge-triggered flops (like OP shows) work too, and require fewer gates (6) than master-slave (8.) Modern CMOS VLSI logic doesn't use either type; instead it uses a pair of latches constructed from T-gates.

Answer (score 0):

To understand how the shift register works you don't have to dig that deep into a flip-flop implementation.

All you need to know is how synchronous sequential logic networks work in general (edge-triggered FFs are just a special case).

A synchronous network only listen to its inputs in a narrow time interval straddling the instant when the active clock edge arrives.

Let's call this interval the *data acquisition interval*. This interval extends from \$t_{setup}\$ seconds before the clock edge to \$t_{hold}\$ seconds after that edge. In the acquisition interval inputs must remain constant to avoid upsetting the network and its behavior.

Moreover **during the acquisition interval the outputs can't change** (that's a fundamental feature of synchronous networks -- they are never transparent, unlike latches).

After the acquisition interval has elapsed, the network stops being influenced by its inputs and enters another phase, let's call it the *output update phase*, which terminates after \$t_{propagation~delay}\$ seconds after the latest clock edge (\$t_{propagation~delay} > t_{hold}\$). Only during this phase the outputs are possibly changed to assume a new state, if this is required by the laws governing the device.

\$t_{setup}\$, \$t_{hold}\$ and \$t_{propagation~delay}\$ are all found in the device datasheet.

In summary, synchronous networks (like your positive-edge-triggered FFs) work with two separate, non-overlapping phases:

- **input acquisition phase**: the inputs must remain constant and the outputs can't change; input data are read into the network;
- **output update phase**: the outputs are updated according to the law of the network, its internal state and the acquired inputs; the inputs can change in any way, since the network no longer is influenced by them.

How does the shift register work then?

Since all FF in the shift register are clocked at the same instant, in that instant each of them acquires as input the value of the output of the previous one.

However, those acquired bits don't get transferred to the output until the data acquisition phase is over. When the output update phase begins, the acquired bits are transferred to the outputs (actually shifting the data along the register), but this won't cause any problem, since the FFs no longer listen to their respective inputs.

Answer (score 0):

> How do shift registers work on the gate level?

They don't. There's no gate level to them.

Apart from a few simple combinatorial input conversion circuits, the shift registers are assembled from flip-flops or other storage elements, not gates, and those elements cannot be further decomposed into only gates. Their building blocks are somewhere between discrete transistors and gates. Their transistor-level schematic has no gate-level equivalents that have any meaning beyond being a teaching/explanatory tool.

> I am trying to understand how a serial to parallel shift register works on the gate level. [...] I found this schematic for a positive edge triggered D flip flop which works great.

Practical edge-triggered flip-flops are transistor-level designs that have no gate-level equivalents that perform the same.

Now, the datasheets sometimes show *gate-level equivalent schematics* of flip-flops and other LSI functions. Those are just to illustrate the *function* of the circuit, not how it's actually designed. If you just took those gates, you'd not really get an equivalent flip-flop. Instead, you'd get a part that performs poorly in practice, although it may look OK "on paper" if you're using rather simplistic models/idealizations of gates.

I urge you to find datasheets that show D flip flops at the transistor level - be it TTL, ECL or CMOS. You'll see that there's no decomposition into basic gates, and the circuits employed to make practical FFs just don't come together from gates at all.

In other words: the gate-level schematic you found is mostly fiction. The only ones who make flip-flops that way are poor students who, lacking better guidance, try to actually assemble those ideas into circuits. They are, for better or worse, the only ones doing that, believe it or not.

Even quite basic gates are often made using rather complex building blocks that don't resemble any simpler logic-level circuits, e.g. multi-input gates aren't just some combination of two-input gates, etc.